# How to download images to the local disk and set image views' images in a view controller?

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

I am going to use my application offline. So, I should download all images that I am going to use in the views.

I am using AFNetworking's cache mechanism. But it is slow while showing the images.

Therefore, I want to download files from server whenever necessary, and set the imageviews's images from a local path.

Is it a good way to do that?

Comment: When you say "AFNetworking's cache mechanism" - are you referring to its use of `NSURLCache`, or the `AFImageCache` used in the `AFNetworking+UIImageView` category?  The latter will be much more performant than the former.

Comment: I am using AFNetworking+UIImageView

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imageURL"]];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
imageView.image = img;

NSString *path = @"your path";
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", {name}, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];

// when accessing it
UIImage *diskImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Or you can use this: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
-- it has caching for offline use, which you may find helpful. It also contains a placeholder image method.

Answer (score 0):

Are these images dynamic? If they aren't, rather than downloading them, you could include them all in the app's bundle so that they're downloaded as the app is initially installed.